# Implementing Notification logic in flutter

Tags: flutter

Am creating a flutter chat app that has different pages. Am stuck at the point where I have to show notification badges. My problem is how to show a badge with the unopened message count on different screens. For example how instagram shows the number of unopened DMs on the DMs icon.

**What Ive tried.**
I was thinking of using providers such that when a message is sent(from a screen called messages.dart), the counter is updated on the home screen(home.dart where the notification icon is located) and also in the allcharts.dart page that contains a list of all chats. However am unable to implement this as am still a beginner with flutter.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can use a global variable to count the unopened message

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called ValueNotifier global variable it holds the single value, set the count to it when new message received, and access that value and show where you want the count.